# Can anyone recomend a place to hire high quality shotgun mics in the UK?

Tags: microphone, field-recording, hardware, gear

I'm trying to find a place where I can hire some better quality shotgun mics from for a short project in the UK.

Curently the best I can find is a 416. Does anyone know or recomend a place where I could hire a Sanken css-5 or Senhiser MKH 70 or equivalent?

Cheers

Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Try Richmond film services, for the Sennheiser MKH70 they charge £12 day rate or £48 per week. They have a real good selection of mics by the look of it including CMIT5Us and pretty much anything else you will need. http://www.richmondfilmservices.co.uk Hope this helps.

Comment: @Lenny That site looks great, v.good selection. Thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Visual Impact - they have outlets in Cardiff, Bristol, London and pretty much everywhere else:

http://www.visuals.co.uk/

Always been very impressed with their service.